# How to filter object array that contains messages from different numbers and leave only last message

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

if for example i have an array that contains all messages sent or received to number 123456789

```
  Messages: [
    { FromNumber: 9999, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "first" },
    { FromNumber: 9999, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "second" },
    { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 9999, Message: "me first2" },
    { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 9999, Message: "me second2" },
    { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 1234, Message: "me first" },
    { FromNumber: 1234, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "second" },
  ],
```

And the result should look like

```
Messages: [
    { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 9999, Message: "me second2" },
    { FromNumber: 1234, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "second" },
  ],
```

I tried something like this but that did not work, what would be the best solution?

```
Messages.filter(
    (v, i, a) => a.findLastIndex((t) => t.ToNumber === v.FromNumber && t.FromNumber === v.ToNumber) === i
  );
```

Comment: Where does "me fourth" come from ? :o

Comment: In addition to above please add more about your logic

Comment: _"but that did not work"_ - because `a.findLastIndex()` will throw an error -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Answer (score 1):

You could collect objects by their key, different from the common key and return the objects.

```js
const
    messages = [{ FromNumber: 9999, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "first" }, { FromNumber: 9999, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "second" }, { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 9999, Message: "me first2" }, { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 9999, Message: "me second2" }, { FromNumber: 123456789, ToNumber: 1234, Message: "me first" }, { FromNumber: 1234, ToNumber: 123456789, Message: "second" }],
    common = 123456789,
    result = Object.values(messages.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = o.FromNumber !== common ? o.FromNumber : o.ToNumber;
        r[key] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked great.